# How to change respectively the width of a TextView in a row according to TextView number?

Tags: android, layout, textview

So, according to my program flow, a have a row View in my activity which is custom populated by TextViews during the program life circle. The problem is that when the TextViews are generated they appear next to each other (Through layout params that I set).

E.x

```
TextView_1 TextView_2 TextView_3
```

What I want is, according to the **number of views** that are genarated ***(every time that acitvity starts, specific number of TextViews are generated)***
to take specific and equal width in the activity, lke below:

[image]

How can I succeed that?

Every little help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the Weight:

For example

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"/>

    <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"/>

    <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

It is important to weight distribution.

If you put 10 the total weight has to be 10.

If you put 3 The total weight must be three.

In other words 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 so the width of 3 elements is dealt.

or also 3.3 + 3.3 + 3.3 = 9.9

Comment: You can also avoid to use weightSum if you don't want to leave any blank space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, If not to use weightSum, I just use weigth in view accordingly?

Comment: Yes, you can use only the layout_weight